# WinInet Implementation in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, wininet

I am looking for a small help regarding JMeter. I have one application that is recorded in LoadRunner using WinInet setting (Port Mapping => Capture Level as WinInet).

Is there a way in Jmeter where we can have WinInet setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box it is not possible, JMeter uses either [Java sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) or [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) in order to execute [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) with its [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request). No OS-specific code is included into JMeter so it can be run on all platforms

If your test relies on some very specific features of [Windows Internet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/portal), be aware that there is no easy way of adding this functionality to JMeter

> **[Developer audience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/portal#developer-audience)**
>
> WinINet is designed for use by C/C++ programmers. It requires a basic understanding of the FTP and HTTP protocols.

So theoretically you can load the .dll(s) implementing WinInet protocol using [JNI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) from [JSR223 Test Elements using Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and call the function(s) you need.

However my expectation is that you don't need this and you can just simply convert your LoadRunner script to JMeter using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) or [online LoadRunner/SoapUI to JMeter script converter](https://shiftleft.blazemeter.com/)

Check out [How to Convert LoadRunner Tests to JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-loadrunner-tests-jmeter/) article for more details.